# Wrong Processor Info

Tags: cpu

I'm using Intel i5-2430M processor which is a dual core processor, but the output of `/proc/cpuinfo` shows four cores. Why? Is is because of hyper-threading?

If yes, is there any way I can see the actual number of cores?

Also, how can I see the sizes of L1 and L2 caches?

Output of `/proc/cpuinfo`: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1206427/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your copy and paste: `cpu cores    : 2`

Could be it right?

As for your cache-question: https://superuser.com/a/203481

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [Intel page](http://ark.intel.com/products/53450/Intel-Core-i5-2430M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz) about your processor specification, It is clear that *Your processor has 2 cores*, So, `cpuinfo` is not wrong by telling you as such.

Also Looking into [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors) and [this page from CPUWorld](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i5/Intel-Core%20i5%20Mobile%20I5-2410M.html) it seems Your processor has

- L1 cache = 2 x 32 KB instruction cache, 2x32 KB Data cache
- L2 Cache = 2 x 256 KB
- L3 Cache = 3 MB